# How to let iPhone 6 use Retina 4 2x image size in Xcode 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, swift, size

I'm using swift for my game, and i need to know how to let iPhone 6 use Retina 4 2x in Xcode.

My images are green-square@2x  green-square-568h@2x  green-square@3x

My objectif : is to force iPhone 6 use Retina 4 2x image for sprite

i use this code to apply image for my sprite

```
                    let GSquare = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "green-square")
```

and How i can load specific image from assets like

```
                    let GSquare = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "green-square-568h@2x")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not *forced* to use the assets catalog that has device-type sized images 1x, 2x, 3x....

You can include PNG or JPG images of any resolution in your app resources directly, and then load the image by its full file name, to ensure that you use a *specific* image resolution sized exactly as you want that way. When you load a specific file, you have to specify the extension in the filename for the UIImage().

Instead of:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "myGraphic") //load from assets
```

Use this form:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "myGraphic.png") //load from file
```

Keep in mind that for `UIImageView`, the image is scaled to the size of your `UIImageView` subview. That means your image will be stretched or shrink if the rectangle you create by the view's frame or Auto Layout constraints is not the exact size of the image you loaded.

You can detect which device you're on like this  in your view controller:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        adjustViewLayout(size)
}

func adjustViewLayout(size: CGSize) {
    switch(size.width, size.height) {
    case (320, 480):                        // iPhone 4S in portrait
          // do something here
    case (480, 320):                        // iPhone 4S in landscape
          // do something here
    case (320, 568):                        // iPhone 5/5S in portrait
          // do something here
    case (568, 320):                        // iPhone 5/5S in landscape
          // do something here
    case (375, 667):                        // iPhone 6 in portrait
          // do something here
    case (667, 375):                        // iPhone 6 in landscape
          // do something here
    case (414, 736):                        // iPhone 6 Plus in portrait
          // do something here
    case (736, 414):                        // iphone 6 Plus in landscape
          // do something here
    default:
        break
    }
    view.setNeedsLayout()

}
```

**Also** *Put this in your viewDidLoad() method so that it is detected the first time the view loads as the other method only detects orientation changes:*

```
adjustViewLayout(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size)
```

Comment: thank you for your help but does this detect if iphone 6 was used or i need to make a verification of the current devise before loading the image ?

Comment: how can i load specific image for assets ?